# Getting data from access with while

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ms-access, while-loop

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("App_Data\\people.mdb"));
            string command = "SELECT * from Files where FileSubjectID=1"; //1 = newsLetters, 2 = Publications, 3 = Videos, 4 = Presentations, 5 = Brochures, 6 = Others
            OleDbDataReader reader = null;    
            string fileType = string.Empty;
            string fileIcon = string.Empty;
            FileInfo file;

            int count = 0;

            try
            {
                using (conn)
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(command, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        conn.Open();
                        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                        Response.Write("bofore whil1e<br/>" + reader.HasRows + "<br/>");
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {

                            file = new FileInfo(reader["FileName"].ToString());
                            fileIcon = setFileTypeIcon(file.Extension.ToLower());

                            Response.Write(count++ + "<br/>");


                            lblNewsLetters.InnerHtml += "<tr><td class='te_al_M'>" +
                                "<table><tr><td rowspan='2'><img src='images/icons/" + fileIcon + ".png'  alt='" + fileIcon + "'/></td><td><span class='te_al_L lblFiles'>" + reader["FileName"].ToString() + "</span></td></td></tr><tr><td><input type='text' style='display:none' id='txtNewName_" + reader["FileID"].ToString() + "'/></td></tr></table></td>" +


                                "<td class='te_al_L' width='150'>" + getUserName(reader["UserID"].ToString()) + "</a></td>" +
                                "<td class='te_al_L' width='70'>" + Convert.ToDateTime(reader["FileUploadDate"].ToString()).ToShortDateString() + "</td>" +
                                "<td class='te_al_L' width='70'><a target='_blank' href='" + reader["FilePath"].ToString() + "''><img src='images/viewBtn.jpg' alt='View file' title='View file'/></a></td>" +
                                "<td class='te_al_L' width='70'><a target='_blank' href='" + reader["FilePath"].ToString() + "''><img src='images/downloadBtn.jpg' alt='Download file' title='Download file'/></a></td>";


                            // only the uploader can change the file name
                            if (isCurrentUsercodeInFile(currentUsercode, reader["FileName"].ToString()))
                            {
                                lblNewsLetters.InnerHtml += "<td class='width_70'>" +
                                    "<a id='rename_" + reader["FileID"].ToString() + "' href='javascript:renameFile(\"" + reader["FileID"].ToString() + "\");'><img src='images/renameBtn.jpg' alt='Rename file' title='Rename file'/></a>" +
                                    "<a style='display:none;' id='save_" + reader["FileID"].ToString() + "' href='javascript:saveFile(\"" + reader["FilePath"].ToString() + "\" , \"" + reader["FileName"].ToString() + "\" , \"" + currentUsercode + "\" , \"" + reader["FileID"].ToString() + "\");'><img  src='images/saveBtn.jpg' alt='Save file' title='Save file'/></a></td>";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblNewsLetters.InnerHtml += "<td class='width_70'>&nbsp;</td>";
                            }


                            // only the uploader can delete the file
                            if (isCurrentUsercodeInFile(currentUsercode, reader["FileName"].ToString()))
                            {
                                lblNewsLetters.InnerHtml += "<td class='width_70'><a href='javascript:delFile(\"" + reader["FilePath"].ToString() + "\" , \"" + reader["FileName"].ToString() + "\" , \"" + currentUsercode + "\");'><img src='images/deleteBtn.jpg' alt='Delete file' title='Delete file'/></a></td></tr>";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lblNewsLetters.InnerHtml += "<td class='width_70'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
                            }
                        }
                        Response.Write("b whil1e<br/>");
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Response.Write(ex.Message);
                conn.Close();
            }
```

I have the code above, ignore all the "Response.Write" and spelling they are only for my testing.

My problem is that to code work locally but not online. The "while(reader.Read())" not executing online I see the message that I am before the while but not the messages in the while loop and not the message on the end of while loop, while locally I see all the messages.

What I am doing wrong? I working on this for two days. If you need more codes, please tell what needed, I sorry if this been asked but I did not find solution to my problem.

Comment: Can you check OLEDB driver is there?

Comment: @AKA, what do you mean to check the OLEDB driver?
How to do it?

Comment: Try to install oledb driver. then it will display that this machine havinf OLEDB or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are swallowing the exception:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Response.Write(ex.Message);
    conn.Close();
}
```

The reason you are not seeing anything after the `while` loops starts is probably an exception which is being thrown, but then swallowed in the snippet above. I would log the exception and analyse that. It is probably something along the lines that you cannot find the file specified in the database:

```
file = new FileInfo(reader["FileName"].ToString());`
```

So therefore throws and fails. **NEVER** swallow exceptions! At least log to a file so you can ascertain what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, that was silly of me.
I got this error:
"Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed. "

Site is stored at godaddy if it is mean anything

Comment: That normally means your application does not have sufficient permission. Go Daddy are probably restricting and is done on a hosting case by case basis. However, you can try adding this to the `web.config` under `System.web` :  `<trust level="Full" />` which should elevate your application to having full trust.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue with Go Daddy? If this has helped please mark as answered to help other people with similar issues. Thank you.

Comment: it help but we decide to move to other hosting where can get better support.
(How do I mark this as answered?)